# Phalcon controller not working using nginx on MAMP

Tags: php, nginx, mamp, phalcon

I'm working on building a website using MAMP + nginx + phalcon. I have everything set up and phalcon is working, but it only sees the IndexController and the indexAction. If I add more controllers and try to navigate to them I get a 404 error. Also if I add another action to the IndexController I can not get to it and I get a 404 error again. Here is my nginx config file:

```
    server {
    listen               7888 default_server;

    root                 "/dev/testing/public";

    location / {
        index            index.html index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files        $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
        fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include          fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

My index.php is the same as the given index in the phalcon documentation.
Any advice/insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your nginx conf should point all requests to your bootstrap file (usually your `index.php`in your public folder) passing the `_url` param containing the original path requested.

That's how the [Phalcon router](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html) works  out of box.

The right configuration block may vary depending on your project's file structure. So you'll need to read [Phalcon's Nginx Installation Notes](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/nginx.html) to see which configurations are needed to your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the documentation of phalcon nginx here https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/nginx.html, I was able to use that kind of configuration because we're passing *_url* param